# How to identify if a link was clicked by a specific email id

Tags: php, email

I am sending emails to a group of people and a link on which the users could click. Clicking on the link would allow user to execute certain functionality. Is there any way using which i can identify which user clicked the link amongst the group, or from which email id the link was clicked.

I am using PHP to generate email template and server is Ubuntu.

Any help in this regards would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when sending mail to a group of users it is not possible to identify which user clicked a link in the mail, the best approach to this i found was to customize the email sending approach and send mails to individual including a link and then take it further from there.

I am not sure if its 100% correct, but i guess this would be the only alternative

Answer (score 0):

when you send link to the user pass username with link or something like that, like this:

```
http://example.com?username=xyz
```

but this is work only for single person means send multiple mail for multiple person.

Comment: Actually, this is the issue....I a, sending emails to group of people and not individual.

Answer (score 0):

is the link reefer to your website?

If yes, then just add one more table in your database.
And add this

When user enter this page, take his ID from the session and add it to the table you created.

if you're sending more than one link. then also add the link or PAGE Proprety like

For example: if your link would look like /index.php?link=something

i would store `$_GET['link']` / `$_SESSION['userid']`

Comment: The user is not logged into my system, when he clicks the link in the email.

Comment: You know, then i don't think so that there is way to store it,
or it's only possible to send it as something.com/index.php?link=123&user=something [ for each user with his userid ] 

to send this link via email! but it's not gonna work because he maybe can change it manually, and it's not secure